# How to merge views in ZStack such that the top view takes precedence?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to recreate the Apple Maps UI, where when a sheet slides up, the sheet kind of merges with the one below it ***where the actual map can still be seen without any reduction in opacity.***

Basically, I do not want the background of the sheet to darken as more slide on top of each other.

Here is a video:
https://streamable.com/x3ugoa

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var views: [Int] = []

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .pink], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Button("Push View") {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.views.append(self.views.count + 1)
                    }
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding()
                
                Button("Pop View") {
                    withAnimation {
                        if !self.views.isEmpty {
                            self.views.removeLast()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding()
                
                ZStack {
                    ForEach(0..<views.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                            Text("Rectangle \(index)")
                                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        }
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                        .foregroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .zIndex(Double(index))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `.opacity` modifier on the "pushed" `ZStack` should do the trick.

e.g.:

```
ForEach(0..<views.count, id: \.self) { index in
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
        Text("Rectangle \(index)")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
    .shadow(radius: 5)
    .foregroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
    .zIndex(Double(index))
    .opacity(index == views.count - 1 ? 1 : 0) //<- here
}
```

Or an even simpler approach, show the views conditionally

```
if index == views.count - 1 {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
        Text("Rectangle \(index)")
            .foregroundStyle(.white)
    }
    .shadow(radius: 5)
    .foregroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .bottom), removal: .opacity))
    .zIndex(Double(index))
}
```

---

Result:

[image: Result]